# Importing Dart package

Tags: dart, package

I've uploaded my package via Pub and it all seemed to work fine. The official page can be found [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/viltage).
The problem is, that I am unable to open this package in my sample project. I've added `viltage: any` to sample's pubspec.yaml and then presseed Pub Get.
The output was:

```
Resolving dependencies...
+ viltage 0.0.1
Changed 1 dependency!
```

Which indicates that it all worked (again), but the viltage package wasn't in the packages folder. Then I've tried adding this line:

```
import 'package:viltage/viltage.dart';
```

to the sample's main.dart file. The file viltage.dart is present in the package. It said that the target URI does not exist and suggested: "Add dependency on package 'viltage'"

The problem I am struggeling with is that I can't use the package I've uploaded to pub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your source on Github, you have to use the [Pub Package Layout](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/package-layout.html) to publish a Package.

your code is a web app not a Dart package.

Comment: Ok. Creating a new project as "Package Template" and the (almost) copying all of the code worked just fine. Thanks for your anwser.

Answer (score 1):

Only files from the `lib` directory can be imported from other packages.